# How to create a column that is filled automatically based on a sequence in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there any way to create a column that is half serial? 
that is imagine that I have the following table:

```
create table item (
     item_number   varchar(10)    PRIMARYKEY,

)
```

but I want the column item_number to be like this: ITEM001,ITEM002,ITEM003 ....
so I want the word ITEM then a kind of a sequence after it.

Comment: create an insert trigger, and use a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a sequence with a default value:

```
create sequence item_number_seq;

create table item 
(
  item_number varchar(10) primary key default 'ITEM'||to_char(nextval('item_number_seq'), '00000')
);
```

But storing the **same** constant value for **all** rows is pretty much useless. Just use a regular sequence and add that constant when you *display* those values. Or use a view to to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Do it at query time or at the presentation layer:

```
create table item (item_number serial primary key);

select 'ITEM' || to_char(item, '999')
from item
```